# Extension inheritance in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

When developing in C#, and you had many classes that used the same exact code, you could rely on another class to hold the generic information, making it easier to modify these classes.

I was wondering if there was anything like that in PHP?

```
class Dog extends Animal {
    private $animalManager

    public function __construct(AnimalManager $animalManager) { 
        $this->animalManager = $animalManager;
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    private $animalManager

    public function __construct(AnimalManager $animalManager) { 
        $this->animalManager = $animalManager;
    }
}

class Fish extends Animal {
    private $animalManager

    public function __construct(AnimalManager $animalManager) { 
        $this->animalManager = $animalManager;
    }
}

class Animal { 
    // Nothing, yet...
}
```

What C# would allow you to do is, store the $animalManager and the constructor assignement in the 'Animal' class somehow, making it constant in 1 place if you ever needed to change it.

Comment: PHP does the same thing. Put the common code in `Animal`'s constructor, and call `parent::__construct()` in the subclasses.

Comment: Read a tutorial on PHP OOP, it should explain how to work with subclasses.

Comment: are you sure that you're speaking about generics? maybe inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, PHP does this quite neatly.Every *extending class* inherits everything from the *extended class*. This means the parent's (in this case `animal`) construct will run whenever you call one of the extending classes.

However, you overwrite your parent's class when you call `__construct()` within the child. Therefore you'd need to specifically call `parent::__construct()` to run the parent constructor.

```
class Animal {
    //Private vars can't be directly accessed by children.
    //You'd have to create a function in the parent return it.
    public $animalManager

    //This function will automatically be called if you leave the
    //constructor out of the extended class
    public function __construct($animalManager) { 
        $this->animalManager = $animalManager;
    }

    //If you want $animalManager to be private
    //Call like $fish->getAnimalManager();
    //Though I do not see the use of this.
    public function getAnimalManager(){
      return $this->animalManager
    }
}

class Fish extends Animal {
     //You do not need to do this if you leave the construct out of this class
    public function __construct($animalManager) {
        parent::__construct($animalManager);
        //Do whatever you like here
    }
}
```

Example with only the parent constructor:

```
class Fish extends Animal {
  //The parent's constructor is called automatically as it's not
  //Being overwritten by this class
  public function test(){
    var_dump($this->animalManager);
  }
}
```

Note that you would also not need to initiate the parent class seperately. Just call it like so;

```
$fish = new Fish(myAnimalManager);
$am = $fish->animalManager;
echo $am;
```

Comment: Thanks! this did the job.

Comment: This does not answer *Generics in PHP?* for sure. These are raw types. The title is something that SO gets its traffic from.

Comment: @aniket sahrawat That's because I realised OP phrased his question wrong.

Comment: Which is why I made an edit suggestion if the title and tags btw.

Answer (score 1):

A draft has been added by Ben Scholzen for generics [here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generics).

But all I can see is type parameters and no wildcards. It supports generic functions and generic constructors. It also supports Bounds.

Unlike C# and Java, PHP will have its type arguments fully reified, which means we can reflectively know the run time parameter of desired function/constructor.

Backward compatibility is not a concern here, because type parameters and raw types can never be compatible. So the legacy code won't be compatible with Generics.

Comment: as far as I can tell - it is only proposal

Comment: @IlyaBursov True, it's a draft.